# Hover span moves down when hovered in firefox but not chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

When you hover the span in firefox it moves down a few pixels but it works fine in chrome. Can't figure why it does this.

```
.close {
width: auto;
right: 4%;
margin-top: 3em;
position: fixed;
z-index: 99;
font-family: 'SuisseBPIntl-Regular';
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
font-size: 15px;
border: solid 1px transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6gohf6nt/

Comment: can't repro on FF40.0 mac

Comment: @Kaiido Huh. Interesting. I'm using a pc with FF40.0. Maybe someone else with a pc can chime in?